# Mysql + Nhibernate + MVC

Tags: mysql, nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-2

I am looking for resources on the web that discuss the implementation of these three tools.

Can anyone help me?

Currently I am referring to the following links:

- http://www.dotnetguy.co.uk/post/2010/02/14/configuring-nhibernate-to-use-mysql-ndash-and-the-small-runtime-gotcha
- http://geekswithblogs.net/pariam/archive/2006/07/26/86352.aspx

Comment: The question is too vague... can you describe a concrete issue you had with this combination?

Comment: Sorry I'm starting a project to develop an application based on these three Framwork. For the moment I want to collect as much information as possible on an implementation of this type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [S#arp Architecture](https://github.com/sharparchitecture/sharp-architecture/wiki) is a nice code base to look at. It illustrates NHibernate integration with ASP.NET MVC. As far as MySql is concerned, well, because you are using NHibernate this is not really relevant and a matter of a simple config switch.